# code not running on PyCharm receiving python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

```
def tab_8():
    nb = 8
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        print(nb, "*", i + 1, "=", nb * (i + 1))
        i = i + 1`
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'tab_8' is not defined

Comment: Can't replicate - may be an issue with your pycharm install.

Comment: do u have any advice for me

Comment: How do you run this code?